# Stick div to top of parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to stick the div to the top of its parent element.

It generally works, except in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/HV9HM/2859/

```js
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $('#container').scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
        $('.stick').css('width', $('#sticky').next().css('width'));
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('#container').scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

```css
.child {
    height: 200px;
    background: gray;
}

#sticky {
    padding: 0.5ex;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 0.5ex;
}
#sticky.stick {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
body {
    margin: 1em;
}
p {
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div id="container" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 800px;">
  <div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
  <div id="sticky">This will stay at top of page</div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that if you scroll the div that is called `container` to the bottom, the div will be scrolled to the top (it's a bug).

If you add another child to div:

```
<div class="child"></div>
```

It works..

You can see the working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HV9HM/2860/

```js
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $('#container').scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
        $('.stick').css('width', $('#sticky').next().css('width'));
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('#container').scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

```css
.child {
    height: 200px;
    background: gray;
}

#sticky {
    padding: 0.5ex;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 0.5ex;
}
#sticky.stick {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
body {
    margin: 1em;
}
p {
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br>
    
    <div id="container" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 800px;">
        <div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
        <div id="sticky">This will stay at top of page</div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
```

(The difference is that the first fiddle has one less child with class `child`).

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that as soon as you give `position: fixed` to your `#sticky` element, it takes it out of the document flow. This means that all of your `div.child` elements shift up, which makes the height of your container element get smaller. Because the container element height gets smaller, the container element no longer needs to scroll, which means its scrollbar disappears and its scroll position is reset to 0. When its scroll position is reset to 0, the script again removes the `stick` class from your `#sticky` element and we are back where we started, but with the container element scrolled all the way to the top.

In summary:

1. `#sticky` element gets `.stick` class.
2. `#sticky` element is removed from document flow, child elements shift up, container element height decreases and scrollbar disappears. Container's `scrollTop` is reset to 0.
3. Script fires again, removing the `.stick` class from `#sticky`, and the container's `scrollTop` remains at 0 (thus the container div is scrolled back up to the top).

Below is a solution that uses `position: absolute` for the `#sticky` element, and when the `#sticky` element gets the `stick` class, it gives the `#sticky-anchor` element a height equal to the height of the `#sticky` element to prevent the child divs from shifting upwards.

---

**Working Live Demo:**

```js
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $('#container').scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    $('.stick').css('width', $('#sticky').next().css('width'));
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky-anchor').height($("#sticky").outerHeight());
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
        $("#sticky").css("top", (window_top) + "px");
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('#container').scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

```css
.child {
    height: 200px;
    background: gray;
}

#sticky {
    padding: 0.5ex;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 0.5ex;
}
#sticky.stick {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
body {
    margin: 1em;
}
p {
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div id="container" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 800px; position: relative;">
  <div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
  <div id="sticky">This will stay at top of page</div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: http://jsfiddle.net/HV9HM/2883/

---

As a side note, the reason it was working fine in your second example is that the additional child element made it so that even when your `#sticky` element was removed from document flow and the container element's height was reduced, the height of the container element was still large enough to keep the scrollbar from jumping/disappearing and changing/resetting your `scrollTop`.

Comment: @AlonShmiel In case you were still interested in a version that keeps the header always at the top of its content, here is a JSFiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/HV9HM/2882/

Answer (score 3):

Although the best answer to this particular question is clearly @MaximillianLaumeister's, here is a general solution for fixing an element to another element.

#### Tether

> Tether is a JavaScript library for efficiently making an absolutely
>   positioned element stay next to another element on the page.
>
> Tether includes the ability to constrain the element within the
>   viewport, its scroll parent, any other element on the page, or a fixed
>   bounding box.

http://github.hubspot.com/tether/

Comment: This is sort of an incomplete answer, since you just linked to a library that does it without showing the code for how to do it.

Comment: @JohnZabroski, I disagree. The answer is complete. Many people may not be interested in this resource. Why clutter the page with code that may be useless to most and would require maintenance on this page? Better to provide a brief description, and for those who are interested, they can visit the site to learn more.

Comment: I was giving you a hint. Bootstrap4 does not even use Tether for this effect, because if you tried it you would understand why. They have a special plug in called Affix just for this purpose, which is what they use for their sticky table of contents.

Comment: @JohnZabroski, I've never used Bootstrap in any of my projects. But thanks for that info. Ultimately, my answer was meant to be a supplement or an alternative to the accepted answer. Nothing major.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr class="relative" id="header">
    <td>header
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="content">
    <td>table content
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 140) {
        $("#header").addClass("fixed");
      } else {
        $("#header").removeClass("fixed");
      }
});
```

take refrence from below example
https://jsfiddle.net/nckv9mso/

Answer (score 0):

along with `position:fixed;`you also need to provide the sticky nav bar a higher z-index value than the other elements of the same page as `z-index:blah;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises when the containers height is x and the content of the container is less than x+36px. In this example the container is 800px and the content is less than 836px. My idea for the solution was to check the height of the content and compare it to the height of the container and if the difference was less than 36px, just not to add the stick class.

Answer (score -3):

its very simple, Just add the following styling for the specific sticky div.

## sticky{position: fixed;}